# integrating gmf with xpand oaw

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gmf, oaw

trying to integrate gmf with xpand.

I created a menu, and command using extensions in gmf manifest file. and am trying to invoke xpand generator.

The code for the command is as shown below

```
public class customCommand extends AbstractHandler implements IHandler {

@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


Shell s=HandlerUtil.getActiveShell(event);
MessageBox mb=new MessageBox(s,SWT.None);


WorkflowRunner runner = new WorkflowRunner();
Bundle bundle=Platform.getBundle("MistScriptGenerator"); 
URL wfUrl = bundle.getEntry("src/workflow/generator.oaw");
String wfFile = "";



try {

wfFile = FileLocator.toFileURL(wfUrl).getFile();
mb.setMessage(wfFile);
mb.open();

Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
//properties.put("model", $diagramFile$.getLocation().toOSString());
properties=null;
boolean isSuccess = runner.run(wfFile,new org.openarchitectureware.workflow.monitor.NullProgressMonito r(), properties, null);


}
catch (Exception e) 
{


}

return null;
}

}
```

I have been able to succesfully get the path for the workflow. 
Now while invoking the workflow I will have to input the gmf diagram file, to the workflow. But how can I give the path for the file ?

I execute my gmf digram by opening it another workbench: 
But, now, how do i get the path of gmf diagram file ?

I have registered epackage in my workflow.

Can you please guide me the project deadline is very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IAML project](http://code.google.com/p/iaml/) uses openArchitectureWare XPand to implement code generation. As an example of how to connect the two together, you can check out the source code for [GenerateCodeAction](http://code.google.com/p/iaml/source/browse/trunk/org.openiaml.model.actions/src/org/openiaml/model/custom/actions/GenerateCodeAction.java#69) -- the relevant method is `doExecute()`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: hi jevon thanks for u r reply but i finished the project two weeks ago. hopefully it should be useful to others :)